# How do you force all li elements in a ul to be the same size as the largest item without setting a fixed size?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of categories on a page, each with a nested list of subcategories. The category list item style arranges the items in a grid pattern (via `display:inline; float:left`), with the subcategories showing underneath in a normal list layout.  The categories and subcategories are user configured, though I don't expect there to be hundreds (probably not more than 10 or 20 subcategories for each of 3 or 4 categories).

I would rather not set a fixed sized for each list item. I would like to draw a border around each element, but I don't like how it looks when each list item size is based on it's content. Is there a way around this without setting a fixed size on the list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with css, you'd have to use javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the `ul` to have `float: left` seems to help.

Example: http://jsbin.com/uluke

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's possible.

```
<div style="float: left"> 
  <div style="display: block">
    <div class="cat">Category #1</div>
    <div class="sub">Sub category #1</div>
    <div class="sub">Sub category #2</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: block">
    <div class="cat">Category #2</div>
    <div class="sub">Sub category #1</div>
    <div class="sub">Sub category #2 LONG LONG LONG</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just because of the way block elements fill to maximum size. I know it's default, just added it to make it more visible. The "float: left" isn't required, but "display: inline" would be.

Comment: Replacing any random element with a div is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the text size of your **average** category item you could use `min-width` to set all items to this size, but allow them to grow for super large items. This could even be set programmatically on render.

Please excuse the huge example.
CSS

```
ul.tags {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    width:40em;
}
ul.tags li {
    display:inline-block;
    /* 
    *  or for FF2 compat use            
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    */
    margin:2px;
    padding:2px;
    min-width:8em;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="tags">
        <li>lorem ipsum dolor </li>
        <li>dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
        <li>sed do </li>
        <li>eiusmod tempor incididunt </li>
        <li>ut labore </li>
        <li>et dolore </li>
        <li>magna </li>
        <li>aliqua</li>
        <li>ut enim </li>
        <li>ad minim veniam</li>
        <li>quis nostrud </li>
        <li>exercitation ullamco laboris </li>
        <li>nisi ut </li>
        <li>aliquip </li>
        <li>ex ea </li>
        <li>commodo </li>
        <li>consequat</li>
        <li>duis aute irure </li>
        <li>dolor in </li>
        <li>reprehenderit </li>
        <li>in voluptate </li>
        <li>velit esse </li>
        <li>cillum dolore </li>
        <li>eu fugiat nulla </li>
        <li>pariatur excepteur </li>
        <li>sint </li>
        <li>occaecat cupidatat </li>
        <li>non proident</li>
        <li>sunt in </li>
        <li>culpa qui </li>
        <li>officia deserunt </li>
        <li>mollit anim id est laborum</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Display: inline and float: left are not a good combination. In fact setting display on a floated element is redundant, as they automatically become block level once floated. (except for a weird ie6 bug with double margins, there is no reason to set display: on a floated element)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to have several cells in a column to have the same width involves tables. IE expressions might work too, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your markup, than:

```
ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

li.category {
    border: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}


<ul>
    <li class='category'>Category #1</li>
    <li>Sub #A</li>
    <li>Sub #B</li>

    <li class='category'>Category #2</li>
    <li>Longer Sub #C</li>
    <li>Sub #D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sub items should be in their own nested UL